# Cursor colour based on input method

Tags: cursor, input-method, coloring

How can I let the cursor colour depend on the current input method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what you get with library [**`cursor-chg.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/cursor-chg.el).

Just turn on minor mode **`change-cursor-mode`**, and leave option **`curchg-change-cursor-on-input-method-flag`** with its default value of `t`.

The cursor color when an input method is used is controlled by option **`curchg-input-method-cursor-color`** (default value `"Orange"`).

(If you do *not* also want the cursor color to change to indicate when a buffer is read-only or is in overwrite mode, then set option `curchg-change-cursor-on-overwrite/read-only-flag` to `nil`.)

See Emacs-Wiki page [Change Cursor Dynamically](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ChangingCursorDynamically).